# Send add-in for Outlook UI

Tags: outlook, office-js

Is it possible for a javascript-based send add-in for Outlook to present a custom UI like you can in the VSTO add-in model?  Based on all the examples I've seen, it looks like they only determine whether the message can be sent based on some analysis performed on the Outlook item.  An alternative solution would be two write two add-ins, one task pane and one send.  The task pane add in would have to be explicitly invoked, which would add another step that my users do not need to perform with the VSTO add-in.  The send add-in would analyze the message to determine whether the task pane add-in has acted on the message.  If there's a way to display a UI in the send add-in, users could still use their existing workflow to get their messages processed as they are accustomed to.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to surface a customer UI using On Send. If the message fails your validation process, Outlook handles surfacing your message:

[image]

Also keep in mind that each add-in runs within it's own sandbox. It isn't possible for one add-in to trigger another or to send messages between two add-ins from within Outlook. You good handle cross-add-in messaging via a shared back-end but this wouldn't help in an On Send scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Learning about the new requirements add-in developers have helps us continue to enable great scenarios on our platform. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user voice page. Please add your request here: 
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins